# Merging two UIImageViews of different sizes

Tags: ios, swift, merge, uiimageview, uigraphicscontext

I am making an iOS app where the user is supposed to be able to overlay one image over another. The user can choose a background image, which would be stored in  a UIImageView called imageView. The user can then decided on a image to be overlaid on top of that image, which will be stored in a UIImageView called imageTwo. Then, the user is allowed to move and resize imageTwo. However, I want to then be able to merge those image views into one image and download it.

I am currently using the function below to try to download the image:

```
@IBAction func downloadImage(_ sender: Any) {
let bottomImage:UIImage = imageView.image!
let topImage:UIImage = imageTwo.image!

let mySize = CGSize(width: (imageView.frame.size.width), height:(imageView.frame.size.height))

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mySize, false, 1)
bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,y:0,width: mySize.width,height: mySize.height))
topImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: imageTwo.frame.origin.x ,y: imageTwo.frame.origin.y , width: (imageTwo.frame.size.width),height:(imageTwo.frame.size.height)), blendMode:CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:1.0)
let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil,nil,nil)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

However, it doesn't work very well.
This is how the image looks in my app:
[Image viewed from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uISuH.jpg)

However, when I download the image using my function from above, the background image looks stretched and the topImage/bird isn't in the right position: [Downloaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENwaX.jpg)

Anyone have any suggestions for easier ways to accomplish this task or how I should change my code from above? I read someone on here suggested putting the UIImageViews into their own View, but that proved to be quite tricky as well...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are compositing the images that back your image views which are different from what is actually displayed by your imageviews.  You can either apply the necessary transform so that the image matches what's show in the imageview or you can be lazy and just capture the image that's on the screen [snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview)